# How can I configure a secure Minifi-C++ instance to pull from a secure C2 server?

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-minifi

I have an issue connecting a **Minifi-c++** instance to a **C2** (Command&Control) server.

I have set up a secure Nifi instance and I have successfully set up a Minifi-c++ instance and a minifi-C2, both connected to the Nifi instance directly.

I have verified that the manually configured Minifi is sending through S2S correctly.

I have also verified that the C2 server can provide a configured template (at least when the request is done from a browser with the right credentials).

Now that I have discarded all connectivity/network and authentication issues, the only thing remaining is to enable the c2 configuration options in Minifi.

```properties
nifi.remote.input.secure=true
nifi.security.need.ClientAuth=true
nifi.security.client.certificate=./conf/cert.pem
nifi.security.client.private.key=./conf/key.pem
nifi.security.client.pass.phrase=./conf/password
nifi.security.client.ca.certificate=./conf/chain.pem
#nifi.rest.api.user.name=
#nifi.rest.api.password=
nifi.c2.enable=true
nifi.c2.agent.protocol.class=RESTSender
nifi.c2.rest.url="https://myUrl:15005/c2/c2-protocol/heartbeat"
nifi.c2.rest.url.ack="https://myUrl:15005/c2/c2-protocol/acknowledge"
nifi.c2.flow.base.url="https://myUrl:15005/c2/c2-protocol"
nifi.c2.root.classes=DeviceInfoNode,AgentInformation,FlowInformation
nifi.c2.agent.heartbeat.period=5000
nifi.c2.agent.heartbeat.reporter.class=RESTReceiver
nifi.c2.agent.class=RemoteMinifyTest
nifi.c2.agent.identifier=CN=test-minifi
nifi.c2.root.class.definitions=metrics
nifi.c2.root.class.definitions.metrics.name=metrics
# ... more metrics stuff
```

The Minifi instance fails anti-climatically with

```
[...::Properties] [info] Using configuration file to load configuration for UID properties
 from ./conf/minifi-uid.properties (located at ...)
[main] [info] MINIFI_HOME=/path-to-minify
[...::Properties] [info] Using configuration file to load configuration for MiNiFi configuration
 from ./conf/minifi.properties (located at ...)
[...::PythonCreator] [info] Adding ... some python stuff
[...::FlowController] [info] FlowController NiFi Configuration file ./conf/config.yml <- empty
[main] [info] Loading FlowController
[...::FlowController] [info] Load Flow Controller from file ./conf/config.yml
[...::FlowController] [info] Loaded root processor Group
[...::FlowController] [info] Initializing timers
[...::FlowController] [info] Loaded controller service provider
[...::FlowController] [info] Loaded flow repository
[...::FlowController] [info] Starting Flow Controller
[...::StandardControllerServiceProvider] [info] Enabling 0 controller services
[...::C2Agent] [info] Class is RESTSender
[...::FlowController] [info] Started Flow Controller
[main] [info] MiNiFi started
[...::TailFile] [error] store state file failed
```

The only thing being registered on the C2 server is

```
DEBUG [qtp1356728614-16] X509AuthenticationProvider Authenticating X509AuthenticationToken
 with principal CN=test-minifi
DEBUG [qtp1356728614-16] C2AnonymousAuthenticationFilter SecurityContextHolder not
 populated with anonymous token, as it already contained:
 'org.apache.nifi.minifi.c2.security.authentication.C2AuthenticationToken@b51a431b: Principal:
 CN=test-minifi; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null;
 Granted Authorities: TEST'
```

which shows up once for every heartbeat

My Minifi instance is identifying itself correctly and the appropriate authorizations have been provided

```yaml
# authorities.xml
CN=test-minifi:
  - TEST

# authorizations.xml
Default Action: deny
Paths:
  /c2/config:
    Default Action: deny
    Actions:
    - Authorization: TEST
      Query Parameters:
        class: RemoteMinifyTest
      Action: allow
  /c2/config/contentTypes:
    Default Action: deny
    Actions:
    - Authorization: TEST
      Action: allow
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing this same problem and so far my research points that minifi-c2 is made to work specificly with MiNiFi Java agent, and its only purpose is to supply config.yml files to them. I have found a way to implement a NiFi C2 server using EFM, cloudera edge management and NiFi Registry here: https://docs.cloudera.com/cem/1.2.0/minifi-agent-quick-start/topics/cem-configure-c2-properties-for-minifi-cpp.html

It's a littly messy but it supplies all required REST service endpoints required for C2 protocol. MiNiFi CPP agent supports full C2 protocol, here you can read a little bit more about the services required for C2 agents and servers https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MINIFI/C2+Design#C2Design-HTTP/SProtocol

Hope it helps, i'm about to test it myself, I'll update my answer with the results.

**ADDED: 15/12/2020**

As suspected MiNiFi C++ agent requires a full C2 Server, so after testing the CEM EFM configuration tutorial everything worked. The only thing I had some issues was on configuring efm to use MySQL db service, so I had to use default H2 storage.

[image: CEM C2 event monitor]

After creating the flow for the MiNiFi class and publishing it, the agent listened to it and retrieved it from th NiFi Registry.

[image: Flow Design for minifi agent]
[image: NiFi Registry Flow]

And after setting (sadly manually) the remote port identifiert to the Remote Process Group Processor, NiFi started receiving data flows from MiNiFi C++ agent.

[image: NiFi Flow]

Hope it helps!

Comment: I cannot test this at the moment but I'll be upvoting just for shear amount of work you put into this answer